# pre-update when I update my password in Edit profile

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello  My pre save its working when i register, but pre update its not working when i change my profile in editprofile.. can anyone knows how to fix  this..

```
userSchema.pre('update', function(next) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
             this.update({},{ $set: {password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8),null) } });   

    next()                                                                                                                                                                          
});  

userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {                                                                                                                                        
    if(this.password) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        this.password  = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8),null);                                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                                                                          
    next()                                                                                                                                                                     
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findOneAndUpdate` and then again run `.save()` to make the password `bcrypted`

```
router.post('/edit', isAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
    User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id}, {$set: req.body},{ new: true }, function (err, user){
        if (err) {
          return err;
        } else {
          if (req.body.password) {
            user.password = req.body.password;
            user.save();
          } else {
            // if body does not contain password
          }
        }
    })
})
```